# How to align text inside a card where the card is inside a ion-slide

Tags: html, ionic-framework, slider, tailwind-css, text-alignment

I have a html page (**example.page.htm**l), where I'm using the ion-slides. In each slide I'm importing the other pages by using the selector(**app-test-1 and app-test-2**). I have ion-card in app-test-1 page, for which I'm not able to give the alignment to make the text in the card to be left aligned.

Alignment works perfect if I directly run the **app-test-1** page but alignment is not proper when I run the **←**(which has the **"app-test-1"** selector).

```
<ion-slides>
<ion-slide>
<app-test-1></app-test>
</ion-slide>
<ion-slide>
<app-test-2></app-test-1>
</ion-slide>
</ion-slides>
```

Comment: make a stakblitz and produce the issue there, cant help with the info provided

Comment: In your example, you have mismatched <app-test-1> and <app-test-2> closing tags. I guess it's only a typo...

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same issue. I had `ion-card` inside `ion-slides` and all the alignments were misplaced.
I tried giving the CSS class for ion-slide with text-left and it worked. I think it's because the ion slide will eventually put it all in the center.

Sample code:
In HTML;

````
<ion-slides>
  <ion-slide class="styless">
    <ion-card>
      <ion-card-header>
        Welcome
      </ion-card-header>
      <ion-card-content>
        HI ... Contenet goes here(without slide-1)
      </ion-card-content>     
    </ion-card>
  </ion-slide>
  <ion-slide>
    <ion-card>
      <ion-card-header>
        Welcome
      </ion-card-header>
      <ion-card-content>
        HI ... Content goes here(slide -2)
      </ion-card-content>     
    </ion-card>
  </ion-slide>

</ion-slides>```

in scss:
.styless {
text-align: left;
}
````